# xml to json string without double qoutes in number and decimal type in c#

Tags: c#, json, xml

I have an XElement I am trying to convert into a JSON string.
Below is my XElement:

```
<myxml>
  <gstin>28GSDUH1331G155</gstin>
  <fp>122016</fp>
  <gt>3782969.01</gt>
  <b2b>
    <ctin>29GSDUH1331G155</ctin>
    <inv p2:Array="true">
      <inum>S008502</inum>
      <idt>15-11-2016</idt>
      <val>10000.00</val>
      <pos>27</pos>
      <rchrg>N</rchrg>
      <prs>Y</prs>
      <od_num>8401</od_num>
      <od_dt>14-11-2016</od_dt>
      <etin>30GSDUH1331G155</etin>
      <itms p2:Array="true">
        <num>1</num>
        <itm_det>
          <ty>G</ty>
          <hsn_sc>G1221</hsn_sc>
          <txval>10000.00</txval>
          <crt>1.00</crt>
          <camt>100.00</camt>
          <srt>1.00</srt>
          <samt>100.00</samt>
          <csrt>100.00</csrt>
          <csamt>100.00</csamt>
        </itm_det>
      </itms>
    </inv>
  </b2b>
</myxml>
```

I am using this  string `jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeXNode(myxml)`;
to convert in json string 
and i am getting the jsonstring

```
"{\"myxml\":{\"gstin\":\"28GSDUH1331G155\",\"fp\":\"122016\",\"gt\":\"3782969.01\",\"b2b\":[{\"ctin\":\"29GSDUH1331G155\",\"inv\":[{\"inum\":\"S008502\",\"idt\":\"15-11-2016\",\"val\":\"10000.00\",\"pos\":\"27\",\"rchrg\":\"N\",\"prs\":\"Y\",\"od_num\":\"8401\",\"od_dt\":\"14-11-2016\",\"etin\":\"30GSDUH1331G155\",\"itms\":[{\"num\":\"1\",\"itm_det\":{\"ty\":\"G\",\"hsn_sc\":\"G1221\",\"txval\":\"10000.00\",\"crt\":\"1.00\",\"camt\":\"100.00\",\"srt\":\"1.00\",\"samt\":\"100.00\",\"csrt\":\"100.00\",\"csamt\":\"100.00\"}}]}]}]}}"
```

The problem that i am running into is that integer and decimal values are being surrounded by backslashes and double quotes(\" \") . I don't want backslash double quotes on numbers and decimals.

This is the JSON string which i want as an output.

```
"{\"myxml\":{\"gstin\":\"28GSDUH1331G155\",\"fp\":122016,\"gt\":3782969.01,\"b2b\":[{\"ctin\":\"29GSDUH1331G155\",\"inv\":[{\"inum\":\"S008502\",\"idt\":\"15-11-2016\",\"val\":10000.00,\"pos\":27,\"rchrg\":\"N\",\"prs\":\"Y\",\"od_num\":8401,\"od_dt\":\"14-11-2016\",\"etin\":\"30GSDUH1331G155\",\"itms\":[{\"num\":1,\"itm_det\":{\"ty\":\"G\",\"hsn_sc\":\"G1221\",\"txval\":10000.00,\"crt\":1.00,\"camt\":100.00,\"srt\":1.00,\"samt\":100.00,\"csrt\":100.00,\"csamt\":100.00}}]}]}]}}"
```

Comment: If you view the actual values - they appear without the blackslashes.  Adding more information would likely help as Jon said below.

Comment: I very much doubt that the string *really* has the backslashes in. Are you looking at this in the debugger by any chance? If so, it would be helpful if you'd print the value out to the console (or similar) and put *that* in the question. The backslashes are just confusing.

Comment: It would also be helpful if you'd convert this into a [mcve]. My guess is that the XML and JSON required to demonstrate this is actually just a very few lines, and it'll be *much* easier to help you at that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have already pointed out - more information would likely help (as your XML is currently invalid).

Also in the future it is always best to show Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable examples to the questions you are asking - not only to show that you have tried, but to give people who are helping more information.

When simply inspecting the element in the debugger as you did it does in-fact show backslashes

```
"{\"myxml\":{\"gstin\":\"28GSDUH1331G155\",\"fp\":\"122016\",\"gt\":\"3782969.01\",\"b2b\":{\"ctin\":\"29GSDUH1331G155\",\"inv\":{\"@Array\":\"true\",\"inum\":\"S008502\",\"idt\":\"15-11-2016\",\"val\":\"10000.00\",\"pos\":\"27\",\"rchrg\":\"N\",\"prs\":\"Y\",\"od_num\":\"8401\",\"od_dt\":\"14-11-2016\",\"etin\":\"30GSDUH1331G155\",\"itms\":{\"@Array\":\"true\",\"num\":\"1\",\"itm_det\":{\"ty\":\"G\",\"hsn_sc\":\"G1221\",\"txval\":\"10000.00\",\"crt\":\"1.00\",\"camt\":\"100.00\",\"srt\":\"1.00\",\"samt\":\"100.00\",\"csrt\":\"100.00\",\"csamt\":\"100.00\"}}}}}}"
```

These backslashes are just inserted as escape characters and are *NOT* actually there.

If you inspect the actual values of `jsonString` you will find your expected value.  When you are viewing the jsonString in the debugger you are looking at a `raw JSON string`, but in the below screenshot you are looking at a representation of a JSON object.

[image]

Comment: yes Its my Fault that i put the string value which was shown in debugger .. actual string is same as you posted .. now i want to remove double quotes from int and float types ...

Comment: @VedPrakashYadav What are you trying to use these values for exactly?  That might help me figure out exactly what you would want to do and I can then edit my answer.

Comment: @VedPrakashYadav If you need more help please let me know - otherwise if my answer has sufficiently answered your question - please consider marking it as the answer.

Comment: actually i am posting this json via rest Api  and i am getting error json structure failed .. this message is comming because some values which are integer and decimal are present in double quotes .. so i just want to remove double quotes ..   like this {"gstin":"28GSDUH1331G155","fp":122016,"gt":3782969.01}   here gstin is string so double quotes is ok but fp and gt are number and decimal it should not be in double qoutes. ...